# Macro to delete rows in excel where cells contain certain text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and not very adept with the programming so I'm hoping for some help here.

Here's the thing:

I have an excel sheet where I need to scan the entire rows and delete rows where Column C and Column D have the text "NA" in the same row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel delete row if column contains value from to-remove-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393524/excel-delete-row-if-column-contains-value-from-to-remove-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I've used before. This applies filters, filters for NA in both column C and D, then removes those rows (excluding the header). Note that this will only remove the row if NA is in BOTH columns. If NA is in C but not in D then it will not remove the row.

```
'Applies filter to the columns. You will want to adjust your range.
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="NA"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NA"

'Removes the rows that are displayed, except the header
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Removes the filter
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to start loop from the end :

```
Sub test()


    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("sh_test") 'edit your sheet name
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'maybe change letter of the column

    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "NA" And ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "NA" Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete     
        End If
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: "NA" is text not a blank cell

Comment: I edited the answer, is it work ? You can adjust the range to find last row (change column letter) and the end of loop (change to "2" for something else)

Comment: Don't use `Integer` for row counting! Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA.

Comment: I would use "UsedRange" to get the rows. "Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows"

Comment: @JC Guidicelli not really

Comment: @inadvisableguy what's wrong ? do you have error message ?

Comment: No, somehow it deletes some other rows in the process as well. @TBoulz 's answer worked fine.  Thanks though :)

Comment: @inadvisableguy I edited the answer, adjust variables sheet name

Comment: Ok no problem !

Comment: @JCGuidicelli `lastrow` will be the last row of `ActiveSheet` you might want to move that behind your worksheet declaration and use `ws.Range…` and also declare `i as Long` too.